# Active Directory (AD) bind to GridView on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I already write a code for retrieved all Active Directory user and it work as a console application. From the code how to bind it to Grid View? I already create grid view with name GVActiveDirectoryUsers

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "unikl"); 
                UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
                PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);

                int i=0;
                foreach (UserPrincipal result in search.FindAll())
                {
                    i++;
                    //    if (result.VoiceTelephoneNumber != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("{3} {0,30} {1} {2} ", result.DisplayName, result.VoiceTelephoneNumber, result.EmployeeId, i.ToString());
                }

                search.Dispose();
                Console.Read();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            }  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView GVActiveDirectoryUsers = new GridView();

GVActiveDirectoryUsers.DataSource = (from UserPrincipal s in search.FindAll()
                                     where s.VoiceTelephoneNumber != null
                                     select s).ToList<UserPrincipal>();
GVActiveDirectoryUsers.DataBind();

<asp:gridview id="GVActiveDirectoryUsers" autogeneratecolumns="true" runat="server"></asp:gridview>
```